# Tool to read html file and save all Javascripts found into one?

Tags: javascript

Is there a tool where I can read all javascripts from an HTML file (or URL) and at the same time minify into a single javascript?

Comment: You want a tool that receives an HTML file, and outputs all of the JavaScript found therein (`<script>` and `<script src>`) into a single JavaScript file? Seems like something you could build easily enough; though there would be several concerns with doing this. Some scripts are intentionally placed in `<head>`, while others at the bottom of `<body>`. Some expect to be in two contiguous `<script>` elements, rather than joined into one. Etc.

Comment: You can use any language (well, one with an appropriate standard library) to create a crawler which extracts `script` tags.

Comment: is there a tool already built to achieve this? I can create an executable, but I want to save time if there is something already

Comment: You could do it pretty easily with a phantomjs script. Compiling an executable to go and fetch and parse the page is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, if you don't mind introducing a dependency on [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (and Node.js) for your build step. Using grunt-usemin will allow you to introduce build comment blocks into your HTML, like so:

```
<!-- build:js dist/master.min.js -->
<script src="vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="lib/base.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

You can read more about usemin on https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin, and here's a nice article from Chris Coyier introducing Grunt: http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/

I'm not sure if there's an automated way of doing this *without* build comments, but you could always write your own if there's not one already available (the plugin directory for Grunt is massive, with new plugins being added every day).

Answer (score 1):

[Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless scriptable browser that could easily be made to do what you want.

You'd need to write a short javascript file to direct it to load a page, download all the script files and concatenate them into a single local file to write out.

You'd probably also have to sideload a javascript minification library and use that to compact your file.