# When using Grunt to build an app, how do you edit the HTML file script and style includes?

Tags: gruntjs

Given `grunt production` (minify, concatenate) and `grunt development` (don't minify, don't concatentate) tasks, how can I have my `index.html` file serve the appropriate files?

For production, `index.html` it should only have one `<script>` tag and one `<link>` tag and for development many.

How do you get grunt to do that?

Comment: [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) is something you should investigate.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. [extra chars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for grunt-usemin, which will allow you to introduce comment blocks around where your minified styles and scripts should go.

https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

> ```
> <!-- build:js dist/master.min.js -->
> <script src="vendor/jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="vendor/underscore.js"></script>
> <script src="lib/base.js"></script>
> <!-- endbuild -->
> ```
>
> [Tool to read html file and save all Javascripts found into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687622/tool-to-read-html-file-and-save-all-javascripts-found-into-one/20688831#20688831)